# Most efficient way to remove N elements from the front of a VecDeque in rust

Tags: rust, deque

What is the most performant way to remove N elements from the front of a VecDeque in rust?

The best I've been able to come up with is:

```rust
let mut v = VecDeque::from(vec![1,2,3,4,5,...]);
v.drain(0..N);
```

But based on my benchmark it's only ~20% faster than the naive:

```rust
let mut v = VecDeque::from(vec![1,2,3,4,5,...]);
for _ in 0..N {
    v.pop_front().unwrap();
}
```

Docs https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html

Comment: So the compiler is pretty good but not perfect at optimizing your trivial code. I don't see the issue. `drain` should be the best.

Comment: Both solutions take roughly the same time for me, which just goes to show that the compiler is very good at optimizing trivial code and that you shouldn't try to optimize until and unless measurements show that you are _really_ spending a lot of time in a specific part of your code.

Comment: I would try `v = v.split_off(N);`. Less code and and most likely faster than looping through the vector. But `v.drain(0..N);` should be similar fast.

Comment: @Kaplan, I tried `split_off` and it's _way_ slower and uses a _lot_ more memory since it allocates space where it copies the tail before discarding the removed items (which btw involves looping through all the items, whereas the naive loop and `drain` only loop through the discarded items).

Comment: @Jmb Very interesting. I was hoping the optimizer would be smart enough not to copy the tail-part, if the head-part isn't assigned anywhere.

Comment: There should be an O(1) way to do this without any allocations by shifting head/tail ptrs and length.

Comment: You can't do it in O(1) if the items stored in the queue implement `Drop`. And it looks like the [current implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/collections/vec_deque/drain.rs.html#115-119) doesn't try even when the items don't implement `Drop`.

Comment: @Jmb I understand that. My example is intentionally a non-drop type. I'm currently just making a copy of the stdlib deque specialized for u8 which can do O(1) `pop front(N: usize)` which seems to be the best option for now ):

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look to be possible with the stdlib.

I've implemented my own QuickDropDequeue. It's basically the stdlib VecDeque with `drop_front` and `extend_from_slice` methods that are much more efficient than what the stdlib does.

This deque is u8 specific but should be easy to modify for any other non-drop type.

https://github.com/n8ta/jawk/tree/main/quick-drop-deque

Sadly I had to mess with the implementation of the RawVec backing the Deque since RawVec is private to the stdlib and not easily reusable. This is NOT production ready code.